# Use of Android AccountManager for my login

Tags: android, accountmanager

I have an app and a `REST API` that allows login via `HTTPS POST` (returning an authentication token) to access certain functionalities. 
Is this a use case for [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)?
My approach would be to ask the user for his credentials, authenticate with my service, store the auth token and use it with the service, reauth with the internally saved credentials to reauth when the token has expired. 
Will `AccountManager` make this any easier for me?

Comment: Yes you can, by writing your own authenticating logic. Refer to this page:
https://web.archive.org/web/20150510142925/http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app and thispage: http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/